# Exact path match in Vue router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am working on a Vue application and want to set up a exact path match for the default route. I have experience in React and Angular and both gave option `exact` and `pathMatch:'full'` so the default route only comes into action if it matches exactly.

In vue, when I refresh my app, the default route gets fired and takes the user back to the first page . Is there a way to do something like that in Vue?

```
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: Home
      // how can I add exact match config here?
    },
    {
      path: "/login",
      name: "login",
      component: () =>
        import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "./views/Login.vue")
    },
    {
      path: "/charts",
      name: "charts",
      component: () =>
        import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "./views/ChartDemo.vue")
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Did you try that: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#exact

Comment: @YomS. Its not about router-link, its about path component mapping. Added code above.

Comment: Must be a bugged version of vue-router or something else is causing that because I have the same setup and it does not do what you are describing. If i am on /login and refresh I am still on /login after.

Comment: related: [vue router options for matching exactPath that ignores query parameters and/or hashes](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2040)

Answer (score 4):

Try putting your routes in this order because Vue-router routes order matters. The matching starts from the top:

```
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/login",
      name: "login",
      component: () =>
        import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "./views/Login.vue")
    },
    {
      path: "/charts",
      name: "charts",
      component: () =>
        import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "./views/ChartDemo.vue")
    },
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: Home
      // how can I add exact match config here?
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Agree that's one way of doing it, but does that mean Vue does not provide any option to handle it gracefully?

Comment: Hum i don't really know but in general routes are placed from particular to general. That's is my rule...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but maybe somebody else can benefit from it.

It seems like Vue Router uses exact match by default. For example I have something like this, and it opens the given component without the use of an "exact" keyword or anything similar.

```
  {
    name: 'Mailbox',
    path: '/mailbox',
    component: Mailbox
  },
  {
    name: 'Message',
    path: '/mailbox/:messageId',
    component: Message
  }
```

Also, [in the documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#catch-all-404-not-found-route) it is shown how to use the asterisk to match all routes that start with a given path. We can then assume this is not the default behaviour of Vue Router.